# how to display color palette in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, colors

In my iPhone app, I want to allow the user to draw image by hand with different colors.

I want the color palette where user can select the color and draw with the selected color.

How can I show the color palette in iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view with several buttons on it. Buttons should have background color also give them different tags (according to color). Now when you press on the button get its tag and then you can get the color from an array (you need to first create an array with color codes or RGB). when you can color code or RGB you can draw with that color.

Post comment if you have confusion

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do this yourself as there is no system color picker. If you don't want to create one from scratch, you might want to look for some existing free project as a code base.

Take a look at [this open source project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-color-picker/), for a start. It's under the BSD license.